# PHP - Project Euler #2

Tags: php

I got the answer fine, but when I run the following code,

```
$total = 0;
$x = 0;

for ($i = 1;; $i++)
{
    $x = fib($i);

    if ($x >= 4000000)
        break;
    else if ($x % 2 == 0)
        $total += $x;

    print("fib($i) = ");
    print($x);
    print(", total = $total
");
}

function fib($n)
{
    if ($n == 0)
        return 0;
    else if ($n == 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return fib($n-1) + fib($n-2);
}
```

I get the warning that I have exceeded the maximum execution time of 30 seconds. Could you give me some pointers on how to improve this algorithm, or pointers on the code itself? The problem is presented [here](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=2), by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say $i equal to 13. Then `$x = fib(13)`

Now in the next iteration, `$i` is equal to `14`, and `$x = fib(14)`

Now, in the next iteration, `$i = 15`, so we must calculate `$x`. And `$x` must be equal to `fib(15)`. Now, wat would be the cheapest way to calculate `$x`?

(I'm trying not to give the answer away, since that would ruin the puzzle)

Comment: Still not sure. If we have the value of fib(14) already stored in x, then there's a way to not have to recurse through fib(15), but use the value of x to make a quicker computation of fib(15)?

Comment: what if you would also have the value of fib(13)?

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Yeah, I rewrote the code not using a recursive function and it sped it up by lots.

Comment: Congratulations! You just earned your [Dynamic Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming#Fibonacci_sequence) badge :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, add caching in fib

```
<?

$total = 0;
$x = 0;

for ($i = 1;; $i++) {
    $x = fib($i);

    if ($x >= 4000000) break;
    else if ($x % 2 == 0) $total += $x;

    print("fib($i) = ");
    print($x);
    print(", total = $total\n");
}

function fib($n) {
    static $cache = array();
    if (isset($cache[$n])) return $cache[$n];

    if ($n == 0) return 0;
    else if ($n == 1) return 1;
    else {
        $ret = fib($n-1) + fib($n-2);
        $cache[$n] = $ret;
        return $ret;
    }
}
```

Time:
real    0m0.049s
user    0m0.027s
sys     0m0.013s

Comment: still way more complex than what is needed in this case though. Also, i think it's bad style to present a solution to a Project Euler problem when only pointers are asked for.

Comment: Given the problem requires calculating `fib(n)` in sequence, caching in this manner is a waste of memory.

Answer (score -1):

You'd be better served storing the running total and printing it at the end of your algorithm.

You could also streamline your fib($n) function like this:

```
function fib($n)
{
    if($n>1)
      return fib($n-1) + fib($n-2);
    else
      return 0;
}
```

That would reduce the number of conditions you'd need to go through considerably.

** Edited now that I re-read the question **

Comment: You're misreading his code. It **`break`s** when `x` is equal to or greater than 4 million.

Comment: Thanks, but does the above function work? I have evaluated fib(2) in the example above as 0.

Comment: `fib(1)` should return 1, not 0.

Answer (score -1):

If you really want to print as you go, use the output buffer.  at the start use:

```
ob_start();
```

and after all execution, use

```
ob_flush();
    flush();
```

also you can increase your timeout with

```
set_time_limit(300); //the value is seconds... so this is 5 minutes.
```